# Toggle between icons if key exists in object and value is true/false

Tags: angular

I am currently working on adding some functionality to my app which allows a user to add/remove navbar menu links to the footer. The code is below:

```
  <div *ngFor="let navbarMenuOption of navbarMenuOptions; let i = index"
       class="row page-row-color page-row-option justify-content-center align-items-center"
       style="font-size: 0.8em" (click)="toggleFooterMenuOptionVisibility(i)">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 0.5em;">
      <button class="btn btn-square btn-options btn-block btn-lg" type="button">
        <i class="ti-close" *ngIf="checkIfFooterMenuOptionIsVisible(i) === false"></i>
        <i class="ti-check" *ngIf="checkIfFooterMenuOptionIsVisible(i) === true"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 row-color h-100 d-table">
      <div class="align-items-center d-table-cell align-middle" style="padding-left: 5px">
        {{ navbarMenuOption }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The above code corresponds with the following UI element:

[image]

Whenever the user clicks the button, toggleFooterMenuOptionVisibility() is called which adds the item to the footer menu link. It works as intended , However, the method checkIfFooterMenuOptionIsVisible(i) doesn't work. It needs to check an incoming object: e.g. `{ Home: true, About: false, Features: false, Contact: false }` and if a key is true, then set the corresponding icon on the button row to a tick. If it is false, or cannot be found, then set it to false.

I'm not 100% clear on why this isn't working, hypothetically it should. My code for the abovementioned method is below. Would appreciate your help:

```
checkIfFooterMenuOptionIsVisible(index: number) {
    let footerMenuOptions = this.builderFooterService.footerMenuOptions.getValue();
    let selectedNavbarMenuOption = this.navbarMenuOptions[index];

    if (footerMenuOptions != null) {
      Object.keys(footerMenuOptions).forEach(function (key) {
        return key === selectedNavbarMenuOption && footerMenuOptions[key] === true;
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  toggleFooterMenuOptionVisibility(index: number) {
    let footerMenuOptions = this.builderFooterService.footerMenuOptions.getValue();
    let selectedNavbarMenuOption = this.navbarMenuOptions[index];

    if (footerMenuOptions == null) {
      footerMenuOptions = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.navbarMenuOptions.length; i++) {
        footerMenuOptions[this.navbarMenuOptions[i]] = this.navbarMenuOptions[i] == selectedNavbarMenuOption;
      }
    } else {
      Object.keys(footerMenuOptions).forEach(function (key) {
        if (key === selectedNavbarMenuOption) {
          footerMenuOptions[selectedNavbarMenuOption] = !footerMenuOptions[key];
        }
      });
    }

    this.builderFooterService.footerMenuOptions.next(footerMenuOptions);
  }
```

Comment: What you're doing right now is going to be extremely costly in terms of performance. The `checkIfFooterMenuOptionIsVisible` method is going to get called a lot of times during change detection. You might want to avoid calling methods in data binding syntaxes like `*ngIf`

Comment: If possible, please consider creating a minimal reproducible stackblitz sample replicating the issue.

Comment: `if (footerMenuOptions != null) {
      Object.keys(footerMenuOptions).forEach(function (key) {
        return key === selectedNavbarMenuOption && footerMenuOptions[key] === true;
      });
    }` this code is not returning from your  `checkIfFooterMenuOptionIsVisible` function it only returns for your `forEach` method. Normally typescript should whine about not all paths returning a value. You should use `return Object.keys(...).some(...)` but you didn't specify your method that returns a `boolean`. Types in typescript can save your precious time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it resolved doing the following:

```
  checkIfFooterMenuOptionIsVisible(menuOption: string): boolean {
    let footerMenuOptions = this.builderFooterService.footerMenuOptions.getValue();
    if (footerMenuOptions && footerMenuOptions[menuOption]) {
      return footerMenuOptions[menuOption];
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```